# Single page scroll with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am struggling to create a web page where there are 2 sections.

- The first section is the complete website except for the menu.
- The second section should be the menu displayed on full screen.

The user should be able to scroll with a nice effect between the two sections.

[Here is a code pen example:](https://codepen.io/olivier-c/pen/XJyNRd?limit=all&page=2&q=one+page)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    /* SCROLL BEGIN */

    a.back-to-top {
      display: none;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      text-indent: -9999px;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 999;
      top: 85%;
      left: 45%;
      background: url("http://www.cleanmyride.ca/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Down-Arrow.png");
      -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
      -moz-border-radius: 30px;
      border-radius: 30px;
    }

    /* SCROLL END*/

  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Pandaniell</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a class="back-to-top" href="#">Back To Top</a>
  <!-- SCROLL BEGIN -->
  <script>
    var amountScrolled = 4800;
    $('a.back-to-top').fadeIn('slow');
    $(window).scroll(function () {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() < amountScrolled) {
        $('a.back-to-top').fadeIn('slow');
      } else {
        $('a.back-to-top').fadeOut('slow');
      }
    });
    $('a.back-to-top').click(function () {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 10000
      }, 1000);
      return false;
    });

  </script>
  <!-- SCROLL END -->
  <div class="container"></div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#home">HOME</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#about">ABOUT</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#where">WHERE</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
      </li>
      <li style="float:right">
        <a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="gradient"></div>
  <script>
    // target to give background to
    var $div = document.getElementById("gradient");
    // rgb vals of the gradients
    var gradients = [{
        start: [128, 179, 171],
        stop: [30, 41, 58]
      },
      {
        start: [255, 207, 160],
        stop: [234, 92, 68]
      },
      {
        start: [212, 121, 121],
        stop: [130, 105, 151]
      }
    ];
    // how long for each transition
    var transition_time = 4;
    // internal type vars
    var currentIndex = 0; // where we are in the gradients array
    var nextIndex = 1; // what index of the gradients array is next
    var steps_count = 0; // steps counter
    var steps_total = Math.round(transition_time * 60); // total amount of steps
    var rgb_steps = {
      start: [0, 0, 0],
      stop: [0, 0, 0]
    }; // how much to alter each rgb value
    var rgb_values = {
      start: [0, 0, 0],
      stop: [0, 0, 0]
    }; // the current rgb values, gets altered by rgb steps on each interval
    var prefixes = ["-webkit-", "-moz-", "-o-", "-ms-", ""]; // for looping through adding styles
    var div_style = $div.style; // short cut to actually adding styles
    var color1, color2;
    // sets next current and next index of gradients array
    function set_next(num) {
      return (num + 1 < gradients.length) ? num + 1 : 0;
    }
    // work out how big each rgb step is
    function calc_step_size(a, b) {
      return (a - b) / steps_total;
    }
    // populate the rgb_values and rgb_steps objects
    function calc_steps() {
      for (var key in rgb_values) {
        if (rgb_values.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            rgb_values[key][i] = gradients[currentIndex][key][i];
            rgb_steps[key][i] = calc_step_size(gradients[nextIndex][key][i],
              rgb_values[key][i]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    // update current rgb vals, update DOM element with new CSS background
    function updateGradient() {
      // update the current rgb vals
      for (var key in rgb_values) {
        if (rgb_values.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            rgb_values[key][i] += rgb_steps[key][i];
          }
        }
      }
      // generate CSS rgb values
      var t_color1 = "rgb(" + (rgb_values.start[0] | 0) + "," + (rgb_values.start[
        1] | 0) + "," + (rgb_values.start[2] | 0) + ")";
      var t_color2 = "rgb(" + (rgb_values.stop[0] | 0) + "," + (rgb_values.stop[
        1] | 0) + "," + (rgb_values.stop[2] | 0) + ")";
      // has anything changed on this interation
      if (t_color1 != color1 || t_color2 != color2) {
        // update cols strings
        color1 = t_color1;
        color2 = t_color2;
        // update DOM element style attribute
        div_style.backgroundImage =
          "-webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, from(" + color1 +
          "), to(" + color2 + "))";
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
          div_style.backgroundImage = prefixes[i] + "linear-gradient(45deg, " +
            color1 + ", " + color2 + ")";
        }
      }
      // we did another step
      steps_count++;
      // did we do too many steps?
      if (steps_count > steps_total) {
        // reset steps count
        steps_count = 0;
        // set new indexs
        currentIndex = set_next(currentIndex);
        nextIndex = set_next(nextIndex);
        // calc steps
        calc_steps();
      }
      if (div_style.backgroundImage.indexOf("gradient") != -1) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(updateGradient)
      }
    }
    // initial step calc
    calc_steps();
    // go go go!
    window.requestAnimationFrame(updateGradient);

  </script>
  <h1>Dit is mijn website</h1>
  <h2><a href="https://www.instagram.com/pandaniell/" target="_blank"><img alt="Instagram" border="0" class="instagram" height="50" src="https://image.ibb.co/nHgkKQ/Instagram.png" width="50"></a></h2>
  <h3><a href="http://facebook.com/daniellwdb" target="_blank"><img alt="Facebook" border="0" class="facebook" height="50" src="https://image.ibb.co/bLf7zQ/Facebook.png" width="50"></a></h3>
  <h4><a href="https://www.dropbox.com/sh/omjvrdt5b3a5x6m/AACYBA_EKBeNzAK1YVQmTtH7a?dl=0"
      target="_blank"><img alt="Dropbox" border="0" class="dropbox" height="50" src="https://image.ibb.co/i2fUDk/Dropbox.png" width="50"></a></h4>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (event) {
      // array with texts to type in typewriter
      var dataText = ["Welkom op mijn website! dit is een voorbeeld tekst"];

      // type one text in the typwriter
      // keeps calling itself until the text is finished
      function typeWriter(text, i, fnCallback) {
        // chekc if text isn't finished yet
        if (i < (text.length)) {
          // add next character to h1
          document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = text.substring(0, i + 1) +
            '<span aria-hidden="true"><\/span>';
          // wait for a while and call this function again for next character
          setTimeout(function () {
            typeWriter(text, i + 1, fnCallback)
          }, 100);
        }
        // text finished, call callback if there is a callback function
        else if (typeof fnCallback == 'function') {
          // call callback after timeout
          setTimeout(fnCallback, 700);
        }
      }
      // start a typewriter animation for a text in the dataText array
      function StartTextAnimation(i) {
        if (typeof dataText[i] == 'undefined') {
          setTimeout(function () {
            StartTextAnimation(0);
          }, 20000);
        }
        // check if dataText[i] exists
        if (i < dataText[i].length) {
          // text exists! start typewriter animation
          typeWriter(dataText[i], 0, function () {
            // after callback (and whole text has been animated), start next text
            StartTextAnimation(i + 1);
          });
        }
      }
      // start the text animation
      StartTextAnimation(0);
    });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.instagram {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20 % % ;
  left: 5 % ;
  bottom: 5 % ;
  right: 8 % ;
}
.facebook {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20 % % ;
  left: 5 % ;
  bottom: 5 % ;
  right: 16 % ;
}
.dropbox {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20 % % ;
  left: 5 % ;
  bottom: 5 % ;
  right: 0 % ;
}
.container {
  width: 95 % ;
  margin - left: auto;
  margin - right: auto;
  height: 1000 px;
}

/* Navigation */

nav {
  width: 100 % ;
  height: 6.5 % ;
  background - color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.13);
}
ul li {
  list - style - type: none;
  float: left;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font - size: 16 px;
  text - align: left;
  margin - right: 25 px;
  margin - top: 25 px;
  letter - spacing: 2 px;
  font - weight: bold;
}
ul li a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text - decoration: none;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.2 s ease;
}
ul li: hover a {
    color: #1115B4;
visibility: visible;
opacity: 1;
}
# gradient {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background: #836997;
}
h1 {
width: 50%;
font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
font-size: 80px;
color: white;
margin: auto;
position: absolute;
top: 30%;
left: 5%;
bottom: 5%;
right: 5%;
}
body {
font-family: arial;
background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-bottom: 100px;
margin-left: 0px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 200;
height: 100%;
{
```

Comment: What is your specific question? Your CSS appears to be invalid so perhaps clean that up first.

Comment: I want my page to look like this: first page: the whole html code except the menu. Second page: The menu with a full screen background other than the main html, I want to show the page except the menu on page load and you should be able to scroll to the second page which is the menu. Also the CSS looks fine when I open my page locally

Comment: Here is a example: https://codepen.io/olivier-c/pen/XJyNRd?limit=all&page=2&q=one+page

Comment: You are telling us what you want. But what is your question? Are you asking people to write the code for you? Or do you have a specific question about the code you have shown us?

Comment: Sorry, I would appreciate it if somebody could write it so I can learn from it

Comment: I doubt that is going to happen for you. But good luck regardless.

Comment: Thank you, I also doubt it but I will check in a few hours